# Redis 5.0.5: WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128

Tags: ubuntu, redis, ubuntu-18.04

I have `windows 10 home`, where is installed `Ubuntu`

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I have installed `Redis 5.0.5` (it mostly with `make` and `make install`)

When I startup the server with `redis-server` it shows some warnings.

I have removed one about `overcommit_memory`

But about:

```
WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
```

I have read these two links:

- [WARNING: /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128. #35](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/35)
- [Performance tips for Redis Cache Server](https://www.techandme.se/performance-tips-for-redis-cache-server/)

Thus both indicate do the following:

- Go to the `/etc` directory
- Create the `rc.local` file, `sudo vim rc.local`
- Add the `sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65535` content and save

I can confirm through

```
cat rc.local
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65535
```

Well in a *secondary* terminal I execute `redis-cli shutdown` and in the *primary* terminal execute again `redis-server`

**Problem** the same warning appears, What is missing?

**Note** I have the same situation even after to execute `sudo chmod +x rc.local`

Comment: It maybe too late but did you reboot your server after `sysctl`

Answer (score 8):

I was facing a similar issue, warnings appearing on logs. I came across the solution with the following:

Try to `echo 1024 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`

add these two, to this file  `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
vm.overcommit_memory=1
net.core.somaxconn=65535
```

if everything  is ok, restart your redis server:
`systemctl restart redis.service`

Check redis logs again:

`cat /var/log/redis/redis.log`

Comment: I'm getting the error when running this inside of Docker.  Any ideas how to fix that?